# How can i access attributes from another class with pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

How can i access the lastname with the pointer in Class 2

```
class Person
    {
    public:
        Person(string firstname, string lastname);
    private:
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
    };
```

My Class 2

```
class Account
{
public: Person getPersonName();
private: const Person* person_;
}
```

.cpp file where lastname should be returned

```
Person Account::getPersonName()
{
    return person_?;
}
```

Comment: Really looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want that getPersonName() returns the lastname. is it not possible with this way?
do i need getter for lastname?

Comment: Private members cann be ONLY accesed from inside the class (some code, for example a getter). Not other class, not even an instance of the class.

Comment: i made a getter 

string Person::getLastName()
{
    return lastname_;
}

and tried to access it

Person *Account::getPersonName()
{
 return person_->getLastName();
}

but it dont work because the pointer is const
can i access  it somehow?

Comment: Declare it as `string Person::getLastName() const`. Note the trailing const. And read up on what const methods vs const references / pointers / objects is all about in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access private member of a class outside the class that contain it.

So in this case you can't access them directly.

However you can create a ***public getter*** in **Person** Class for the member **lastname** and then call it in the `Person Account::getPersonName()`.

In alternative you can define lastname public ( this approch is not recommended ).

Another way is to use friend class. I leave you a useful link:

[Friend Class](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)